# How do I get lsyncd 2 working?

Tags: 10.10

I tried to compile lsyncd [from the sources](http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/downloads/list), it gives this error: `make[1]: *** [luac.out] Error 1` even though I had done `apt-get install liblua5.1-0-dev liblua50-dev liblualib50-dev`.

The lsyncd avaialble in apt-sources is 1.35, which doesn't have ssh support. How can I get lsyncd 2 working on ubuntu 10.10?

Comment: Can you do a pastebin link of the whole compile output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to have it compile successfully by just installing the following (same version of Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install lua5.1 liblua5.1-0-dev
```

Then

```
./configure && make
```

This is in an environment where all the normal build/compile tools are already installed, so if you were to link a pastebin of your compile process, maybe we can see if something else is missing.